# Is there way a to include a directory from set of directories in Visual Studio Code “Explore” tab?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Hi all I am starting to use vs code with a project with large numbers of sub modules. However , I am working with only few modules so That showing the entire folders (about 50) is not something I want. As far as I can find, there is setting to exclude files.

```
"files.exclude": {
    "**/.git": true,
    "**/.svn": true,
    "**/.hg": true,
    "**/CVS": true,
    "**/.DS_Store": true

}
```

I want to know is there a capability to include only the folders I want?

Comment: I can't find any explicit include.  I tried to exclude all true and then exclude one folder false afterwards but it didn't work sequentially - just excluded them all.  And I tried some glob negation patterns to no avail.